# Remove trailing '/' from rails string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So i have this command at the moment, ITs breaking up a URL to get the ID from said URL

The URL has a forward slash on the end. Which is currently bringing in the ID like this

```
1111111/
```

I need to remove the forward slash on the end so its like `1111111`

Heres what i have at the moment

```
  var apis = '<%= @event.slink.split('-')[-1] %>';
```

I have currently already tried putting .gsub on the end however that didnt work (I may have not done this right however)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var apis = '<%= @event.slink.split('-')[-1].gsub(/\/$/, '') %>';
```

Comment: Hey,I'm needing to have the split put on as its a full url until its split

Answer (score 2):

For your simple case use chop, which returns a new String with the last character removed.

```
"1111111/".chop #=> "1111111"
```

If you need extracts URIs from a string and to remove more end chars:

```
require 'uri'

CHARS = %{.,'?/!:;}
URI.extract(text, ['http']).collect { |u| CHARS.index(u[-1]) ? u.chop : u }
```

Demo:
[image]